# Cannot get Equalizer to work!!! It just won't do anything at all

Tags: android, equalizer

I've tried ALL of the methods found on stackoverflow.com, this Equalizer instance just won't respond at all.
I just want it to do the very basic stuff!

I have my min project API level at 16.

I test on a Galaxy S6 (Android 5.1.1 API 22)

```
// create : media player + equalizer
private void init() {
    Log.d(TAG, "initMediaPlayer: ");
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        equalizer = new Equalizer(0, mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
        if (equalizer.setEnabled(true) != Equalizer.SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "initMediaPlayer: FAILED");
            return;
        }
        equalizer.usePreset((short) 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "initMediaPlayer: ", e);
    }
}


// use next preset
private void useNextPreset() {
    short presetCount = equalizer.getNumberOfPresets();
    short index = equalizer.getCurrentPreset();
    index++;
    if (index >= presetCount) index = 0;
    equalizer.usePreset(index);
    Log.d(TAG, "useNextPreset: " + equalizer.getPresetName(index));
}

// show music picker
private void popPicker() {
    popActivity(FilePickerIntent("audio/*"), new IntentRequestResultForward() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(boolean ok, Intent data) {
            if (ok) play(data.getData());
        }
    });
}

// play music from uri
private void play(Uri uri) {
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Log.d(TAG, "play: playing...");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "play: error ", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working for me, just heard some beautiful music. Make sure to include

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In your manifest, above the `application` tag.

Answer (score 0):

would you like to try this example ?

http://kevinboone.net/android_simple_eq.html

let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: for me it's showing `An error occurred while loading the archive`